# how to check whether the number ends with 9 or not in numbers 1to 100

Tags: c#, c++

How can I to print the numbers from 1 to 100 in the following format?

```
1-------------9
10------------19
20-------------29
30--------------39
40-----------49
50-----------59
60-----------------69
70---------------79
80---------------89
90-----------------99
```

Comment: Smells of homework to me.  BTW did you actually have a question?

Comment: So what is stopping you? What problems are you having?
Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @UncleBens: smells like an answer, so why post it as a comment?

Comment: It's not even very good homework, you could brute-force it with a loop and ten if statements.

Answer (score 17):

Just check whether the number modulus 10 equals 9:

```
if (number % 10 == 9) …
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [modulus operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html).

Answer (score 3):

The modulus operator (%) will give you the remainder of a division. When you divide a number by 10, the "remainder" will give you the last digit.

```
int lastDigit = number % 10;           // this is the remainder of (number/10)
if (lastDigit == 9)
{
    // whatever you want to do here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( ( num % 10 ) == 9 )  
{  
  // I end in 9  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 9; i < 100; i += 10)
    Console.WriteLine(((i==9)?1:i-9) + "----------" + i);
```

Should print pretty much exactly what you asked.

```
for (var i = 9; i < 100; i += 10)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Will print just your result

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( x == 0x09 || x == 0x13 || x == 0x1d || x == 0x27 || x == 0x31 || x == 0x3b || x == 0x45 || x == 0x4f || x == 0x59 || x == 0x63 )
```

or

```
if ( strchr( "\x09\x13\x1d\x27\x31\x3b\x45\x4f\x59\x63", x ) )
```

---

For those with no sense of the ridiculous, why are these more insane than `x%10 == 9` ? in `x%10==9` you have introduced two magic numbers rather than several, and turned a structured problem with no conditional behaviour  (print rows, each row having  columns) into a single loop with conditional behaviour.

Comment: I can't upvote this on principle, but I gotta say sometimes I think these are the best kind of answers to homework questions. If someone isn't willing to figure it out themselves on something as relatively simple as this, they're probably not really meant for computer science. I'd rather that they figure that out while in class instead of while working on a critical project with me.

Comment: could this be code-golf?

Comment: I gave the modulus answer because the OP requested a single loop – but I have to admit that a single loop + modulus here isn’t as clear a solution as two nested loops. Why didn’t you just post this solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
    if (i%10==0)
    {
        if (i==10)
        cout<<i-9<<"--------"<<i-1<<endl;
        else 
        cout<<i-10<<"--------"<<i-1<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 100)
{
  i+=1; 
  while(i % 10 != 0)
  {
    Console.Write(i);
    i+=1;
  }
  Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: There is no way these two while loops will ever stop.

Comment: Damnit, forgot the increment.